# How to know if my connected microphone is being used by any user? (Python OR Linux x84-64)

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, microphone

I'm writing a program and I need to be notified if the microphone connected to my system is used by any program.
Is there a way to do this in Linux or Python?

By the way, my microphone is connected via a USB cable and it is basically a webcam that has a microphone in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your microphone is some `/dev/media0` on Linux, you could use `lsof` from https://github.com/lsof-org/lsof to find the [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) using it. See also [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [lsusb(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsusb.8.html)

On Debian, see also [hwinfo](https://packages.debian.org/buster/hwinfo).

Comment: thanks a lot for your useful answer! if you could help me about this on windows i would be grateful

Comment: I never used Windows in my life (and my first program was in 1974).